# Will 12V2A break smaller pc fans?

Tags: fan, adapter

Currently I have a 12V2A adapter that powers 2x 12V0.3A/12cm pc fans.

I want to bring in an additional 12V0.4A/23cm fan to the circuit.

The question: can the new setup cause any harm to the fans or adapter?

Or should I bond them together in serial? Or parallel? Or somehow I should check that the adapter is regulated or not?

I can't afford new fans, adapter if they would burn down. Also I can see a +-10% sign on the 23cm fan, next to the V/A numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't. If your fans are rated for 12V, then applying 12V to them won't break them. Just connect them all in parallel, and as long as their current demand doesn't exceed the current rating of the supply, you'll be fine.